# iOS Twitter SLRequest returning url domain error -1012

Tags: ios, twitter, oauth, nsurlconnection, twitter-oauth

I am attempting to perform reverse oauth to get twitter access tokens for a server.

I have figured out how to submit the request and receive a response, but when I do, it gives me this error:

```
Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1012.)
```

I looked this up, and it says that it means the user has canceled the request. I am not sure how this is possible, and I cannot figure out how to fix it.

Here is my code:

```
NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];
    NSNumber *timeStampObj = [NSNumber numberWithDouble: timeStamp];

    NSString *oauth_nonce = [self genRandStringLength:32];
    NSString *oauth_timestamp = [timeStampObj stringValue];

    NSURL *feedURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token"];

    NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"my key here", @"oauth_consumer_key", oauth_nonce, @"oauth_nonce", @"HMAC-SHA1", @"oauth_signature_method", oauth_timestamp, @"oauth_timestamp", @"1.0", @"oauth_version", @"reverse_auth", @"x_auth_mode", nil];

    SLRequest *twitterFeed = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:feedURL parameters:parameters];

    twitterFeed.account = self.userAccount;


    // Making the request

    [twitterFeed performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Check if we reached the reate limit

            if ([urlResponse statusCode] == 429) {
                NSLog(@"Rate limit reached");
                return;
            }

            // Check if there was an error

            if (error) {
                NSLog(@"The Error is: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                return;
            }

            // Check if there is some response data
            if (responseData) {

                NSLog(@"%@", responseData);

            }
        });
    }];
```

There must be something simple I am missing, and this is keeping me from finishing a project. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: More specifically, this error code is that the user cancelled authentication. Most likely this is because some first attempt at authentication failed, and so the system decided to cancel auth, rather than retrying. Is there anything interesting in `urlResponse`?

Comment: When outputting it only shows this: <NSHTTPURLResponse: 0xbe7adf0> Any idea how to pin point the problem? Thanks for  response

Comment: If this makes any difference, when I change the request url by adding /test just for the heck of it, I actually get a response. It is an error of course because the URL is invalid, but it runs the code the way its supposed to. Switch it back to the stand URL and I get the same error. Is it possibly something to do with my parameters I am supposed to set? This is really frustrating!

Comment: `NSHTTPURLResponse` is fully documented by Apple. Look up its methods and poke around at those

Answer (score 1):

Error code -1012 can be due to an authentication challenge. In my case, a Twitter account existed in Settings, but was not logged in for some reason. Once I entered the password for the account, everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem when I sent a request to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token with an extra nonce and signature in the header. Specifically, the following code gave me a 1012, but the next chunk of code succeeded. This code is adapted from [Sean Cook's Reverse Twitter Auth example](https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample).

```
/**
 *  The first stage of Reverse Auth.
 *
 *  In this step, we sign and send a request to Twitter to obtain an
 *  Authorization: header which we will use in Step 2.
 *
 *  @param completion   The block to call when finished. Can be called on any thread.
 */
- (void)_step1WithCompletion:(TWAPIHandler)completion
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:TW_OAUTH_URL_REQUEST_TOKEN];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{TW_X_AUTH_MODE_KEY: TW_X_AUTH_MODE_REVERSE_AUTH,
                           TW_OAUTH_NONCE:[self nonce],
                           TW_SIGNATURE_METHOD: TW_SIGNATURE_METHOD_VALUE,
                           };

    TWSignedRequest *step1Request = [[TWSignedRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:dict requestMethod:TWSignedRequestMethodPOST];

    TWDLog(@"Step 1: Sending a request to %@\nparameters %@\n", url, dict);

    [step1Request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            completion(data, error);
        });
    }
```

The following works. Note the change in the `dict`.

```
/**
 *  The first stage of Reverse Auth.
 *
 *  In this step, we sign and send a request to Twitter to obtain an
 *  Authorization: header which we will use in Step 2.
 *
 *  @param completion   The block to call when finished. Can be called on any thread.
 */
- (void)_step1WithCompletion:(TWAPIHandler)completion
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:TW_OAUTH_URL_REQUEST_TOKEN];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{TW_X_AUTH_MODE_KEY: TW_X_AUTH_MODE_REVERSE_AUTH};

    TWSignedRequest *step1Request = [[TWSignedRequest alloc] initWithURL:url parameters:dict requestMethod:TWSignedRequestMethodPOST];

    TWDLog(@"Step 1: Sending a request to %@\nparameters %@\n", url, dict);

    [step1Request performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            completion(data, error);
        });
    }
```